# Functions jQuery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery code that I seek to have in php ->

My jQuery:

```
var coolDates = [Date.parse(new Date(2018, 10, 15)), Date.parse(new Date(2018, 10, 16))];
```

My PHP:

```
public static function getGreetingProduct($id_product)
{
    $sql = Db::getInstance()->executeS('
        SELECT bp.id_block_location_period, bp.is_recurring, bp.date_start, bp.date_end, bp.minimum_retail, bp.rate
        FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'block_location` bl
        LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'block_location_period` bp ON(bl.id_block_location_period = bp.id_block_location_period)
        WHERE bl.id_product = ' . $id_product
    );

    $array = ['greetings' => []];

    foreach ($sql as $period) {

        if (!$period['is_recurring']) {

            $begin = new DateTime($period['date_start']);
            $end = new DateTime($period['date_end']);
            $end = $end->modify('+1 day');

            $period = new DatePeriod(
                $begin,
                new DateInterval('P1D'),
                $end
            );

            foreach ($period as $key => $item) {
                $array['greetings'][] = $item->format('Y ,m ,d');
            }
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

My PHP code is currently returning this:

```
["2018 ,09 ,10", "2018 ,09 ,11", "2018 ,09 ,12", "2018 ,09 ,13", "2018 ,09 ,14", "2018 ,09 ,15", "2018 ,09 ,16", "2018 ,09 ,17", "2018 ,09 ,18", "2018 ,09 ,19", "2018 ,09 ,20", "2018 ,09 ,21", "2018 ,09 ,22", "2018 ,09 ,23", "2018 ,10 ,22", "2018 ,10 ,23", "2018 ,10 ,24", "2018 ,10 ,25", "2018 ,10 ,26", "2018 ,10 ,27", "2018 ,10 ,28"]
```

And he would have to refer that:

```
[1542236400000, 1542322800000]
```

From what I understand this is the date format like this in JS `2018, 10, 12` + a `strtotime()`.

But I can not do it in PHP...

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you please reformulate? Especially the "he would have to refer that" part. What date format do you want to obtain from that PHP script?

Comment: I would like in PHP that I refer this format here: [1542236400000, 1542322800000]

Comment: Looks like you just want a microtimestamp.  That's the `u` format.

Comment: Are you looking to convert the string `'2018, 10, 12'` into a unix timestamp in php? If so you can just do `strtotime('2018, 10, 12')`